# How do I loop a set of strings in reverse in Python?

Tags: python, string, loops, reverse

Without using reversed(), how would I loop a set of strings in Python in a function?

Stumbled upon ranges like:

> range() and xrange() take a third parameter that specifies a step. So
>   you can do the following.
>
> range(10, 0, -1) Which gives
>
> [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]  But for iteration, you should really
>   be using xrange instead. So,
>
> xrange(10, 0, -1)

But these don't really speak to strings?

Comment: A set has no inherent ordering, so the concept of iterating over a set “in reverse” doesn't make sense.  Do you mean a list of strings?

Comment: "But these don't really speak to strings?" You could try and see

Comment: This question is vague. Can you show some code? Sample input and desired output? Do you really have a "`set` of strings" or are you using "set" casually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  These are useful in that you don't have to iterate over a sequence, which is what `range` and `xrange` (in 2.x) provide.

`str` can be iterated over and sliced, much like strings.  The only difference is that `str` elements are immutable.

To your example, say you have a set of strings and you want to iterate over them.  No problem - just remember that sets have no inherent ordering to them; they only guarantee that the contents are unique.

```
myset = set(["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"])
for i in myset:
    print i
```

...which prints:

```
second
fifth
fourth
third
first
```

It's also the case that you can reverse a single string by itself using [the step parameter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) for a sequence type, of which `str` belongs.  You can do that with this:

```
"this is the song that never ends"[::-1]
```

...which prints:

```
'sdne reven taht gnos eht si siht'
```

Comment: Makoto got what I was looking for. Yeah, I was using the word set more casually! Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
>>> str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> str[::-1]
'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'
```